# media query won't take precedence

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have some simple CSS and HTML just to see if the media query work. But something wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
    .box {
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px
    }
    /* Mobile Phones */
    @media screen and (max-device-width:640px)  {
        .box {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The box background won't change to blue when viewing in mobile. I use firefox plugin "Go Mobile" to simulate mobile screen environment during the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/r56m37kb/

`max-width` instead of `max-device-width`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect syntax for your media query.  Here is a working snippet with comments on where to make the change (max-width vs max-device-width):

```css
 .box {
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px
    }
    /* Mobile Phones */
    @media screen and (max-width:640px) /* Changed from max-device-width */  {
        .box {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```